# Changing Recycler View item based on its data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

So I have a POJO with a question, and in my recycler I wanna show a question itself with answers and correct answer should have the background color.

When I try to add background color, items get colored based on some serious magic.

First few items do not get any color, and closer to the bottom of the recycler here is what happens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO6he.png)

The further the better, when I scroll from the bottom to the top, items at the top get the color as well.

```
        public void bind(Question question) {
        int correctAnswerNumber = question.getCorrectAnswer();

        switch (correctAnswerNumber) {
            case 1:
                answer1.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
                break;
            case 2:
                answer2.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
                break;
            case 3:
                answer3.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
                break;
            case 4:
                answer4.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
                break;
        }
```

}

The context here is passed from the activity, and I have to ideas what to do.
I tried to remove the logic to the constructor, change the context, address items through holder, didn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a classic case of "stale state from a recycled view item".

**Your Problem**

You only set the background for a correct answer. When that item view is recycled and used for an incorrect answer, you are not updating it and it keeps the old background that was set on it.

**The Solution**

Always explicitly set the full state of a recycler item view. In this case, set the background for whatever it should be when it's not a correct answer.

```
public void bind(Question question) {
    int correctAnswerNumber = question.getCorrectAnswer();

    // Reset all backgrounds to default before setting the current correct one
    answer1.setBackground(getDefaultBackgroundBorder());
    answer2.setBackground(getDefaultBackgroundBorder());
    answer3.setBackground(getDefaultBackgroundBorder());
    answer4.setBackground(getDefaultBackgroundBorder());

    switch (correctAnswerNumber) {
        case 1:
            answer1.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
            break;
        case 2:
            answer2.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
            break;
        case 3:
            answer3.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
            break;
        case 4:
            answer4.setBackground(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.correct_answer_border));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This totally worked. Thank you sooooooo much.

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted to indicate the question is resolved.